# Android - onClick of button not working in adapter inside a listview that is inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, onclicklistener

I hope my title makes sense, basically I have a button inside a listview a layout as an adapter in a listview inside a fragment.

My problem is that my onClick method deleteQuote(View v) is not recognized when I declare it in the fragment class. It errors out something about not found in the main activity. So I transferred it to the main activity, but the problem is that I needed the view tag to get a primary key in the entry via the getTag to delete that entry in the database and in the adapter of the listview. Where should I put my onClick method where in i can still get the view tag or What is the best way to do this implementing setonclicklisteners?

Fragment class

```
public class QuotationList extends Fragment{

ListView lvQuotationsMotorcar;
ArrayList<Quotation> menuList_motorcar;
CustomMotorcarQuoteAdapter cmqa;

ListView lvQuotationsFire;
ArrayList<Quotation> menuList_fire;
CustomFireQuoteAdapter cfqa;

Button btnDeleteQuote_motorcar;

Spinner spQuotationType;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_online_quotation_list, container, false);

    lvQuotationsMotorcar = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvQuotationsMotorcar);
    menuList_motorcar = new ArrayList<Quotation>();
    cmqa = new CustomMotorcarQuoteAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.motorcarquotationlayout, menuList_motorcar);
    lvQuotationsMotorcar.setAdapter(cmqa);

    lvQuotationsFire = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvQuotationsFire);
    menuList_fire = new ArrayList<Quotation>();
    cfqa = new CustomFireQuoteAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.firequotationlayout, menuList_fire);
    lvQuotationsFire.setAdapter(cfqa);

    final SQLiteDatabase mydatabase = getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase("INLIS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    spQuotationType = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spQuotationType);
    btnDeleteQuote_motorcar = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnDeleteMotorcarQuote);

    Cursor resultSet = mydatabase.rawQuery("Select * from QuotationMotorcar", null);
    if (resultSet != null){
        if (resultSet .moveToFirst()) {
            while (!resultSet.isAfterLast()) {
               //stuff
                cmqa.add(q);
                resultSet.moveToNext();
            }
        }

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Pending Motorcar Quotations", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    Cursor resultSet1 = mydatabase.rawQuery("Select * from QuotationFire", null);

    if (resultSet1 != null){
        if (resultSet1 .moveToFirst()) {
            while (!resultSet1.isAfterLast()) {
               //stuff
                cfqa.add(q);
                resultSet1.moveToNext();

            }

        }

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Pending Fire Quotations", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    mydatabase.close();


    //more code

    return rootView;
}
```

onClick method deleteQuote

```
public void deleteQuote_motorcar(final View v){

    final SQLiteDatabase mydatabase = getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase("INLIS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Warning!");
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this quote?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            Quotation itemToRemove = (Quotation)v.getTag();
                            cmqa.remove(itemToRemove);
                            mydatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM QoutationMotorcar WHERE QuoteNumber =" + itemToRemove.getQuoteNumber() + "; ");


                        }
                    })

            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();


}
```

This works perfectly fine if it just extends an activity class. Hope someone can help. I'm really annoyed on how this onClick is not working on Fragments.

How and where can I declare my method where in it can be called properly with the view tag?

Comment: for deal with row you can use listview.setonitemclick instead set onclick inside adapter

Comment: @AjayPandya But I have another button in the layout entry that needs the tag also. The other one gets the view tag and sends it to the database server. I just showed 1 in my example which is the delete part for people to get the point.

Comment: from where you call the delete method

Answer (score 0):

Use this declaration of `OnClickListener` in your custom Adapter `getView` method

```
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_lv_item_layout, parent, false);
    view.findViewById(R.id.your_bt).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //do what ever you want
         }
    });

    return view;
  }
```

Instead of `public void deleteQuote_motorcar(final View v)`